# C# SoapFormatter blocking

Tags: c#, soap

I have a client server applications in C# to send objects from the client to the server and back.
When the server is disconnected, the client thread is still in blocking mode on the Deserialize method. How can I "notify" the client to close the stream and stop the blocking Deserialize when the server is down?

Here is my client handler:

```
public void ConnectToServer(string alias, string color)
{
    try
    {
        client = new TcpClient();

        MyMessage firstMsg = new MyMessage();
        firstMsg.Message = "MyNewClient";
        firstMsg.SenderName = alias;
        firstMsg.ClientColor = color;

        client.Connect(ep);
        isClientConnected = true;

        stream = client.GetStream();
        formatter = new SoapFormatter();

        formatter.Serialize(stream, firstMsg);

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    MyMessage msg = (MyMessage)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                    GotMessage?.Invoke(msg);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Debug.Write("ConnectToServer():: failed to deserialize");
                }      
            }
        }).Start();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("Server is offline. Try again later");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Do not create infinite loops. 2) Do not catch `System.Exception`. 3) Do not throw away stack traces. 4) Do not catch exceptions you cannot handle. 5) do not use `Thread`, use `Task`. 6) Use `async`/`await`